# Rename WooCommerce sorting dropdown options

Tags: customization, woocommerce-offtopic, sort

How to rename the WooCommerce sorting dropdown options and customise the wording? For example, change "Popularity" to "Best Selling" or "Price: Low to High" to just "Price Low to High" without the colon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code to functions.php and rename the relevant option. Here I have renamed the 'Popularity' option to 'Best Selling'.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'rename_sorting_option_woocommerce_shop' );

function rename_sorting_option_woocommerce_shop( $options ) {
   $options['popularity'] = __( 'Best Selling', 'woocommerce' ); 
   $options['date'] = __( 'Newest', 'woocommerce' ); 
   $options['price'] = __( 'Price: Low to High', 'woocommerce' );
   $options['price-desc'] = __( 'Price: High to Low', 'woocommerce' );  
   return $options;
}
```